# Cannot ping localhost when resolv.conf.d/head modified

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns

I have observed this behaviour since about a week ago, and I don't think I have changed any related configurations.

The problem is that when I run `ping localhost`, I get the following error:

```
ping: unknown host localhost
```

The same also happens when I ping by my machine host name. This has also caused another problem: whenever I run commands with `sudo`, I get `sudo: unable to resolve host [myhostname]`.

I later took a look at my `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`. Previously (a long time ago) I added a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` on it. After commenting this line out, `ping` works correctly as expected.

Also note that this behaviour occurs only when connected to the Internet through Wi-Fi. I don't have the chance to test connection through Ethernet though. But if I am disconnected then everything works as normal.

What is the cause of this, and how can I prevent this behaviour and keep 8.8.8.8 as my name server?

Comment: What does `/etc/hosts` look like? `localhost` is a special name and should be resolved locally only.

Comment: @saiarcot895 /etc/hosts is correct. It has localhost mapped to 127.0.0.1 and my host name mapped to 127.0.1.1. (I'm not an idiot...)

Comment: What's the output of `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf`? Also, you may or may not be an idiot, but idiotic mistakes happen to the best of us.

Comment: @muru `grep: /etc/nsswitch.conf: No such file or directory` But I'm quite sure I have never touched this file before...

Comment: @muru Fixed this problem with `echo 'hosts:files dns' | sudo tee /etc/nsswitch.conf`. Posting this here in case I'm still doing something wrong... (well maybe I *am* an idiot after all...)

Comment: @ace Who knows? :P Seriously, `nsswitch` also contains other entries that you may or may not need down the line. Maybe you could update your question to be about rebuilding nsswitch.

Comment: @muru I think I'll just copy the file from a Ubuntu VM. I don't think I need anything more than the default one.

Comment: Good. Can you then post that echo | tee command as the answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @muru Answered but cannot mark as accepted until 2 days later. (I hate it when you lose privileges after offering a bounty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out somehow my `etc/nsswitch.conf` is missing (no idea why though).

Fixed this problem with `echo 'hosts:files dns' | sudo tee /etc/nsswitch.conf`, but maybe a better option will be to obtain the default `nsswitch.conf` file.